# Problem about a recursive sequence $a_n = \sqrt{\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}}$ with initial conditions $a_0=8\text{ and }a_1=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

I am trying to solve the recurrence relation
$$a_n = \sqrt{\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}}$$ with initial conditions
$$a_0=8\text{ and }a_1=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Can anyone please help me with the technique to approach this problem?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far, and what are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take logs and it becomes
$b_n = \dfrac{b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}}{2}
$.
This has been investigated here.

Note that
$a_0a_1^2 = 1$.
That is not a coincidence.

Comment: Thank you this really helped.